# NameError with exec function

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in Python. I'm trying to apply some dynamics function (`startswith()`, `replace()`, exec..) defined as string.

I've this code:

```
access_number = 'CF-12345' 
condition = 'str({v}).startswith("CF-", 0)'

result = {}
exec (condition.format(v = access_number)) in r
```

but I've this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/main.py", line 11, in <module>                                                                                                         
    exec (condition.format(v = access_number)) in r                                                                                                  
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                               
NameError: name 'CF' is not defined
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: this is a Bad Idea. Putting code in strings and executing those strings leads to all kinds of issues and I am certain there is a nicer way to achieve what you want. I suggest you write `def condition(v): return v.startswith("CF-")` and try to forget `exec` exists for now.

Comment: can you show the rest of the code? Without knowing what r is this is a little tricky to know what's happening. Most likely there is an escaping issue, so it's executing `CF-` as in variable CF minus whatever, not `"CF-"`

Comment: `exec` is a horrible newbie trap. It is very difficult to use correctly, full of subtle caveats, and almost never a good idea. Most of the time, if you think `exec` is the right tool, what you really need is a function or a data structure.

Comment: oh, you mean result, I see.

Comment: I know that exec is a bad "command" (maybe like eval).
I've a web interface where users defines some rules to apply before process CSV file. So functions and parameters are dynamics (startwith() and 'CF-' in this case).

Answer (score -1):

Try using print statements as your diagnostic, if you run

```
access_number = 'CF-12345'
condition = 'str({v}).startswith("CF-", 0)'

result = {}
print condition
print condition.format(v=access_number)
exec (condition.format(v = access_number)) in result
```

the output is

```
str({v}).startswith("CF-", 0)
str(CF-12345).startswith("CF-", 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stuff.py", line 8, in <module>
exec (condition.format(v = access_number)) in result
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'CF' is not defined
```

Notice the second line has `str(CF-1234)` this is trying to subtract 1234 from the variable CF.

try

```
access_number = '"CF-12345"'
condition = 'str({v}).startswith("CF-", 0)'

result = {}
exec (condition.format(v = access_number)) in result
```